# If the `-p` flag not needed anymore in `mkdir` 9.0?

Tags: linux, coreutils, mkdir

I can't find any reference of this change of behaviour

```
$ mkdir --version
mkdir (GNU coreutils) 9.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David MacKenzie.
```

None of the folders exists.

```
$ mkdir asdfg/qwerty
mkdir: created directory 'asdfg'
mkdir: created directory 'asdfg/qwerty'
```

However, with mkdir (GNU coreutils) 8.25 the behaviour is as expected.

```
➜  ~ mkdir asdfg/qwerty
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘asdfg/qwerty’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I don't suppose you have it aliased or overridden as a function to include the `-p`?

Comment: I truly believed I didn't have t aliased. My surprised when I found it was...`mkdir is aliased to mkdir -pv'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I compiled latest coreutils from source and I still need to use `-p` to create directory with parents:

```
$ src/mkdir --version
mkdir (GNU coreutils) 9.0.11-13af8

$ src/mkdir a/b
src/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘a/b’: No such file or directory
```

So you either have an alias for `mkdir -p` (and probably also with `-v` for verbose output because `mkdir -p` doesn't print the information about creating the directories) or coreutils is patched by your distribution.

Comment: Indeed. I just found out I had the oh-my-bash general.aliases enabled